# Choose jdk location for NetBeans

Tags: java

I want to install NetBeans but I need the location of jdk where that's Installed. I installed it by dnf in fedora 25. Can anyone help me to how find the location of installed package jdk???

Comment: `which java` might give you a starting point, assuming envar JAVA_HOME isn't already set. You'll likely will have to hunt through a chain of links.

Comment: also check that `netbeans_jdkhome` in `etc/netbeans.conf` is not set, because if it is, this JDK path will be used.  If it is not set, the default JDK will be used.  Others have answered how you can find the default JDK path.

Answer (score 0):

`echo $JAVA_HOME` or `$ which java` to get location of jdk.

Answer (score 0):

Try either of below.

```
$ which java    
$ whereis java
```

This will give you the location of installed JDK.

Comment: Thanks for your helps but I tried all of your solutions but already netbeans can not find jdk folder.But I have "java" command in my terminal

Comment: I have this result : java: /usr/bin/java /usr/lib/java /etc/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz... I tried all of these path but netbeans still can't find jdk folder